# Write data in cell into csv file based on dictionary value

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm trying to write data to an CSV column based on a dictionary value.
For instance, I have a for-loop which will generate one dictionary in each loop

```
{JLKJ: 1}
{BNMM: 4}
{HUGF: 5}...
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PNC6.jpg)

My goal is to try to append a new value to a corresponding column based on the key value, if column doesn't exist, must add column and append its value.
For example like new keys come in let's say

```
{GRAR:2} 
{GLPO:2}
{JLKJ:3}
```

[example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fo5k.jpg)

I know CSV module doesn't play too well in terms of such tasks. Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Will the keys be column headers or just the preceding row?

Comment: @pstatix that's correct, keys will be column headers

Comment: Can each key have multiple values? Or only one value? As an extension, in your CSV file, will each column have only one row? Or will it have multiple rows?

Comment: @SaravanaKumar each key will have just one value and each column will have multiple rows depending on how many new {key:value} generated from the loop

Comment: Can you show the function in its entirety? Need to see how you are implementing your generation and file i/o

Answer (score 0):

I find this design a bit jarring. Is there a specific reason why you use only one key with a dictionary? What you could do instead is keep a single dictionary where each value is a list of elements for that particular key. So your code would look something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dic = defaultdict(list)

for......
    dic['XYZ'].append(val) #At the end of your for loop dic = {ABCD: [1,2,3,4], EFGH: [5,6,2,4,8]....}

rows = dic.values()
rows = zip(*rows)  #Both CSV and zip don't support variable length lines, so make all arrays of equal length by padding zeroes to the end before this line

with open('filename.csv','wb') as fp:
     fieldnames = dic.keys()
     writer = csv.writer(fp)
     writer.writerow(fieldnames)
     writer.writerows(rows)
```